# Why can't attributes of "custom defined" classes be set (in java (7))?

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, broadcast, android-broadcast

I'm working on an android project that overrides the code of `BroadcastReceiver`:

```
private void registerBroadcastReceiver() {
    final IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
    intentFilter.addAction(REQ_ACTION);
    intentFilter.addAction(RESPONSE_ACTION);

    this.broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        private Object syncObject;
        private WebServer webServer;

        public void setSyncObject(Object obj) {
            this.syncObject = obj;
        }

        public void setWebServer(WebServer webServer) {
            this.webServer = webServer;
        }

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            printIntentInfo(intent);
        }
    };
    // Registers the receiver so that the service will listen for broadcasts
    this.registerReceiver(this.broadcastReceiver, intentFilter);
}
```

where `registerBroadcastReceiver` is called in `onCreate()` (in a service).

Whenever I try to call `setSyncObject()` in broadcast receiver:

```
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Starting web server");
        syncObject = new Object();
        try {
            webServer = new WebServer(getApplicationContext(), PORT_NO);
            broadcastReceiver.setSyncObject(syncObject); // <= ERROR HERE
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "\nCouldn't start web server on port " + PORT_NO + "\n");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        ...
    }
```

I get an error:

```
Cannot resolve method setSyncObject in BroadcastReceiver
```

The answer seems obvious, just create a new receiver that extends bc and add the methods there. But I'm curious as to why the methods can't be seen(, unless they're resolved at compile time).

Even when creating a separate object:

```
public class CustomBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private Object syncObject;
    private WebServer webServer;

    public void setSyncObject(Object obj) {
        this.syncObject = obj;
    }

    public void setWebServer(WebServer webServer) {
        this.webServer = webServer;
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        printIntentInfo(intent);
    }
}
```

the attribute has to be cast to its type

```
((CustomBroadcastReceiver)broadcastReceiver).setSyncObject(syncObject);
```

Comment: `broadcastReceiver` is an anonymous inner class implementation of `BroadcastReceiver`. From the standpoint of anyone outside of that implementation, `broadcastReceiver` is just a `BroadcastReceiver`, without any custom methods.

Comment: Correct. It's strange that the object has to be cast to its type even when it's of inherited type.

Comment: "the attribute has to be cast to its type" -- or, declare the field to be of type `CustomBroadcastReceiver`. By declaring the field to be a `BroadcastReceiver`, you are specifically, intentionally saying that you do not want to use it as a `CustomBroadcastReceiver` and that you only want to access the `BroadcastReceiver` API. If you later change your mind, you will need a cast.

Comment: Whoops ... tunnel vision